# PancakeView Lebel Text Binding not working

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.forms, nuget

I am using PancakeView Nuget in my xamarin forms project, this is my code:

```
<yummy:PancakeView Margin="0,32,0,0" BackgroundColor="#E96C20" Padding="20,0"
                               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="150" CornerRadius="20">

                 <Label Text="{Binding Points}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Large"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="#000000" />

                <yummy:PancakeView.Shadow>
                    <yummy:DropShadow x:Name="shadow" Color="Gray" Offset="30, 30"/>
                </yummy:PancakeView.Shadow>

            </yummy:PancakeView>
```

As you can see I'm trying to bind a string from my view model called points, heres the C# code for it as well:

```
public class PointsPageViewModel : ContentPage
   {
       public string Points = "0";
   }
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working even though I do define the Binding context in the beginning of the xml file:

```
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:yummy="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="MyProject.Views.PointsPage" Title="POINTS">
     <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:PointsPageViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

So I do not know why this is happening, binding works fine outside the pancakeview so I do not understand why it would not work within it.
If anyone has encountered this issue before and knows how to solve it, please let me know!

Comment: I believe you are mixing things here, a ViewModel is not supposed to sub class ContentPage, also you need to read [data-binding-basics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics).

Comment: you can only bind to **public properties**.  `Points` is **public** but it is not a C# **property**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You xml classes need to look like code below to deserialize properly

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xml);
            XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContentPage));
            ContentPage contentPage = (ContentPage)serializer.Deserialize(xReader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms")]
    public class ContentPage
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ContentPage.BindingContext", Namespace = "http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms")]
        public BindingContext BindingContext { get; set; } 
    }
    public class BindingContext
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModels")]
        public string PointsPageViewModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```